# Read a docx file that is inside a zip file without extracting it

Tags: python

I'm trying to read information from a docx file that is inside a zip file. The zip file is not in my disk, I retrieved it using a REST API, just for you to know.

I tried many approaches and none of them worked. I managed to use the zipfile library to read the zip file and see all the documents inside it, including the docx file, managed to print the docx file in bytes too, but whenever I try to decode it to utf-8 I get the error:

```
"utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte"
```

And if I try to decode in latin-1 or any other decoder, it returns strings that I cannot understand at all.

This is the code I tried using:

```
file1 = io.BytesIO(response.content) 
file = zipfile.ZipFile(file1)

file_names = file.namelist()
word_file = file.namelist()[1]  #the position of the word file in the zip file

file_word = file.open(word_file).read()
```

I also tried the docx library to open the docx itself, but it doesn't work (I think because I have it in bytes).
My main struggle is really converting the bytes into something readable.
**I just need to retrieve some data from the word file**, it has some text in there and tables I need, and I can't extract it because I have more than a thousand zipfiles, every single one of them with several files (although I only want the docx file).

Would really appreciate it if you could help me. Thank you.